# Why in python does the list(range) way much faster than the [i for i in range()] way when creating a number sequence?

Tags: python

I'm using python3.6. For my computer creating a 1e8 number sequence, the former way would spend about 3 seconds while the latter way spent 10 more seconds.

Just as the title has presented I wonder what's the difference between the two ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that CPython is not a very performant implementation of Python. CPython barely ever does much optimizations even when such optimizations might be trivially simple, this is deliberately done to keep CPython implementation simple.

For the long answer, continue for the next few paragraphs.

The key to understanding the performance difference between list () and list comprehension is in the disassembly:

```
import dis
N = 10000
def m1():
    return list(range(N))
def m2():
    return [i for i in range(N)]
dis.dis(m1)
dis.dis(m2)
```

The disassembly for m1 outputs:

```
  8           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (N)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

as the disassembly shows, the entire conversion is just a single bytecode instruction which is function call to the `list` method, and the entire implementation of `list` is in C.

On the other hand, the disassembly for the list comprehension:

```
 11           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (N)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             19 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 RETURN_VALUE
```

as the disassembly shows, a list comprehension is a lot more complicated than `list(range(N))`, but more importantly is that the looping of the list comprehension happens over multiple bytecodes instruction. Processing each bytecode costs an entire interpreter loop, with the interpreter fetching the next bytecode, figuring out what to do, and executing the bytecode instruction, all these overhead does not exist in `list()`.

So yes, the implementation of `list` is significantly more efficient than list comprehension, so yes you would want to just call `list` if all you want to do is realize a generator and not use any of the other list comprehension features.